# Получить кусок из исходного кода

Tags: javascript

Вопрос такой:
нужно скрыто открыть страницу на этом же домене, получить часть исходного кода и вывести алертом пользователю.

Ладно, элемент на странице я получу регуляркой, а вот как открыть без выскакивающих окон со страницей и пр - мне не ясно.

Comment: не нужно регулярку, просто сделайте элемент (не обязательно его показывать) и в нем стандартные поиск. а еще можно без ajax - iframe задать, и не обязательно его показывать.

Comment: @eicto там документ с флешем, который громко начинает материться. 
Аяксом тоже как бы не совсем выйдет, ибо это юзерскрипт намечается

Comment: т.е. генерацию сайта вы не контролируете, тогда лучше никак.